# Does OpenID Connect standardize the OAuth 2 Authorization Endpoint?

Tags: http, security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Does OpenID Connect standardize the OAuth 2 Authorization Endpoint?  IIUC the OAuth spec allows providers to vary the endpoints, so just curious if OpenID Connect locks it to a specific URI value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't. But what it does do, is [specify how](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderMetadata) to *discover* the URL of the correct endpoint, using:

```
GET /.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1
```

And then pick the `authorization_endpoint`. [Here](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration) and [here](https://connect.authentiq.io/.well-known/openid-configuration) are two real world examples.